# Using Anko SQLLite, what is the best way to check if a database exists?

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, anko

I'm working on an Android app using Kotlin and as part of the startup process, I would like to determine whether or not a SQL Lite database already exists (meaning the user is not a new user)

I've so far been unable to determine what is the best way to do this using the [ManagedSQLiteOpenHelper](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-SQLite) helper infrastructure from the Anko SQLLite helpers.

```
        database.use {
        // what should go in here???   
        }
```

I don't necessarily want to query a non existent table and thus throw an exception and use that as a form of logic control, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question.

This works

```
this.query("sqlite_master", arrayOf("name"), "name='userInfo' AND type='table'", null,null,null, null,null).count
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this:

```
db.use{
  select("youtTableName").whereSimple("fieldId = ?",id).exec {
      //your code here
  }
}
```